# Clearing the browser cache deletes Tempdata in Asp Net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i have an application which uses tempdata internally. When i clear browser cache i loose the tempdata. Tempdata internally uses sessions then how come the data is lost? Can anyone please explain? thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tempdata) .The cookie-based TempData provider(create `CookieTempDataProvider` cookie) is enabled by default. To enable the session-based TempData provider, use the `AddSessionStateTempDataProvider` extension method which will create  a session cookie named as `.AspNetCore.Session` , but both of them will be deleted by clearing browser cache(cookie) operation .